# Using python to create a yaml file - list formatting

Tags: python, yaml

I have a python script that outputs a yaml file using `yaml.dump(yaml_dict, file_path)`

The output is formatted something like this:

```
name: joe
type: builder
tables:
- table_name_1:
    exclusion:
    - column_a
    - column_b
    site: location_c
- table_name_2:
    exclusion:
    - column_d
    site: location_b
```

This is very close to how I want the output to look, but slightly out in terms of the formatting of the table names. This is what I want:

```
name: joe
type: builder
tables:
  table_name_1:
    exclusion:
    - column_a
    - column_b
    site: location_c
  table_name_2:
    exclusion:
    - column_d
    site: location_b
```

That is, I want no hyphen before the list of tables, instead I just want the indentation via spaces.

The code I am using to add the tables to the `yaml_dict` is as follows:

```
table_list = df['table'].tolist()
    for table in table_list:
        table_config = {'site': df.loc[df['table'] == table, 'site'].item()}
        exclusion = df.loc[df['table'] == table, 'exclusion'].item()
        er_list = exclusion.replace(' ', '').split(",")
        table_config['exclusion'] = er_list
        table_dict = {table: table_config}
        yaml_dict['tables'].append(table_dict)
```

I am happy to keep the hyphens in the list of exclusions, but I don't want them in the list of tables. Is there anything I can do to remove them?

Comment: "That is, I want no hyphen before the list of tables" Then it needs to be a dict, not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dashes mean that you are ouputing a list. Instead, you need a dict.

Assuming you initialize it something like this:

```
yaml_dict['tables'] = {}
```

Then in the for loop:

```
yaml_dict['tables'].update(table_dict)
```

Comment: That makes sense, although I am getting an error saying `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'extend'`

Comment: It looks like `.update()` might be what I need instead

Comment: @nimgwfc Thanks for the correction. I wrote this from memory and looks like I got it wrong.